# React.js close all the previous containers at the same time

Tags: reactjs

I got the container with children coming from props.[Container][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y7Qm.png . When i click the arrow button it shows the content of the container. [Content][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8eZH.png . When i open the content container i want other containers  to close . For now i can only close them with clicking the arrow button again.[Open Content][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/REh57.png .Here is my code `

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Question(props) {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    function clickedElement() {
        return setClicked(!clicked);
    }

    return (
        <div className="question-cont">
            <div className="question-cont-inner">
                <h3>{props.head}</h3>
                <button onClick={() => clickedElement()}>
                    {clicked ? (
                        <img src={props.img2} />
                    ) : (
                        <img src={props.img} />
                    )}{" "}
                </button>
            </div>
            {clicked ? <p>{props.description}</p> : ""}
        </div>
    );
}
```

`Here is the my parent component`

```
import Question from "../components/Question";
import questions from "../components/Questions";

export default function Sorular() {
    const questionList = questions.map((question) => {
        return (
            <Question
                key={question.id}
                id={question.id}
                head={question.head}
                description={question.description}
                img={question.img}
                img2={question.img2}
            />
        );
    });
    return (
        <div className="sorular-container">
            <div className="sorular-top">
                <div className="sorular-top-back-img">
                    <a href="/">
                        <img
                            src="./images/right-arrow-colorful.png"
                            id="right-arrow-img"
                        />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="sorular-top-head">
                    <img src="./images/conversation.png" />
                    <h4>Sıkça Sorulan Sorular</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="sorular-bottom">{questionList}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`

Comment: This is offtopic, but you have your static data saved in a file `../components/Questions`, but it is clearly used to _generate_ your component structure as an entry data. You should move it from `components` into directory like `static` or `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove your `const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);` state variable from the component itself and move it into parent:

In parent add this at the beggining and modify `questionList`:

```
const [clickedElementId, setClickedElementId] = useState(null);

const questionList = questions.map((question) => {
    return (
        <Question
            key={question.id}
            id={question.id}
            head={question.head}
            description={question.description}
            img={question.img}
            img2={question.img2}
            isOpened={question.id === clickedElementId}
            onClickedElement={() => setClickedElementId(
                question.id === clickedElementId ? null : question.id
            )} 
        />
    );
});
```

And in the `Question.jsx`, swap button for the following:

```
<button onClick={() => props.onClickedElement()}>
    {props.isOpened ? (
        <img src={props.img2} />
    ) : (
        <img src={props.img} />
    )}{" "}
</button>
// and later:
{props.isOpened ? <p>{props.description}</p> : ""}
```

This works by your app holding `id` of only one, currently open question, and swap it based on clicked element.
Note that `questionId` should be unique amongst all `Question` components, but you probably use `.map` to render them so you should use the same variable as you are passing into `Question`'s `key` prop while rendering.

Comment: Added main component

Comment: Modified my answer, should work as expected now

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working cause i have to modify that part too   '{clicked ? <p>{props.description}</p> : ""}'

Comment: Sorry I have missed it, should work now